# How can i make react native modal to be 50% of the screen and still see the animation of the window scaling when opening the modal

Tags: react-native

Can't make react native modal to 50% of the screen

I set transparent to true but then i can't see the animation of the window and can't close the modal by dragging it down. I added a draggable element to close it but still doesn't do what I want. Does anyone have any ideas how can i achieve the goal.
I want like this but 50% of the screen height
[https://i.ibb.co/4RXBz5j/Screenshot-2023-09-12-at-8-00-44-am.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOGfU.png)

Comment: Check if [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) can give what you want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ThanhalPA I tried that but then the window doesn't scale down when the bottomsheet opens and scale up when it is closed